# How to conditioanlly hide group header in crystal report based on a column value in details section

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

I hope some one must have dealt this situation before.

I have a crystal report and on that report I have different sections including headers ,detail and footer. I'm displaying parts related information on details section and description is one of the fields thats being displayed.

So now based on part's description(in detail section)I have to display some text on the page header. So I have to look for part's description for every single part ,and if even a single part has the given description out of all the parts I have to print a message on report header.

My assumption is to use conditonal suppress option at the page header section, but not sure how to check for values from details section at the page header level.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks 
NAF

Comment: You want to display it in page header or report header? You mentioned both.

Comment: The answer will depend on which header you mean. Like Robert mentioned, you don't specify which. Are you trying to hide the group, page, or report header?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I would approach it.

Create a formula which returns 1 when your condition is met- otherwise 0. For example:

`if {table.field} like '*acid*' then 1 else 0;`

Then your conditional surpression can sum your new formula- and if the result is 0 it will hide the message.

`sum({formula}) = 0`

Comment: +1 This is how I would do it for the report and/or group headers. I don't think summaries will work in a page header though.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to display it in *Report Header* then i would use a **SQL Expression** to conditionally suppres the text you want.

The SQL Expression

```
(select count(1) from dbo.TABLE where description = 'my_description')
```

Then in the Suppress formula:

```
{?SQL_EXPRESSSION} = 0
```