# Crystal Reports || Show Text when Report is Blank

Tags: crystal-reports

​I have a crystal report which has 5 subreports. When there is no data then the report is coming as blank which is working as expected.

Now I have added a new Report Header section in the main report and added a static text (not from the database). So, when I am running the report whether it is blank or has data, the new section should be visible. So, it this section is visible only when the report has data. When there is no data, then this section is also not visible.

There is no suppression or formatting in this section but still, it is not showing in case of a blank report. I tried adding New Page Header Section also, Page and Report footer section also but it is not coming in any case when the report is blank.

Any suggestion to show that section in both cases, with and without data?

Comment: yes, add a page header with show /hide condition and before adding this section bring the count of record of your subreport which tell you true/false.

Comment: Thank You @Ajay2707 . I tried this but the problem is when there is no record nothing is visible. If I add new report header or page header or report footer or page footer with static data (i.e. text field with some text) and run the report then this newly added section is also only visible when there is data. If there is no data then this section is also not visible. I don't know what I am missing. Which property is hiding everything on report when there is no data.

Comment: please share your screenshot and any condition in section expert

Comment: check here https://ibb.co/s2t72Qt  . Yellow highlighted sections are static sections means not bound to any data.

Comment: ok now understand, it always visible. So conditionally set the visible, do you set report parameter linking between main report and sub-report   or  do you have any database-field/column which associates with your main report as well as sub-report, if yes, then add a group, thent put the header static text and sub-report there and set hide condition and also true for blank report.  see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166565/programmatically-hide-text-lines-in-a-crystal-report

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116705/how-to-conditioanlly-hide-group-header-in-crystal-report-based-on-a-column-value

Comment: Problem is different, the static text you see in the Yellow Highlighted sections, comes only when there is data in the report. But when there is no data in the report then it doesn't come. These sections I have added in the main report. I know how to hide and show sections based on the condition. But without adding any condition, these sections are not appearing when there is not data in the report. I want to show them in both cases i.e with or without data .

Comment: I though you did not want and I think that always comes without anything and you place at header side. you can shift that static text in group header or report header where you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the same question on sap website and had long discussion. If anyone facing this issue, can check the thread at below link
https://answers.sap.com/questions/13453443/crystal-reports-show-text-when-report-is-blank.html